# java.lang.InternalError when generating excel file with apache-poi on alpine in java 11/17

Tags: java, docker, apache-poi, java-11, alpine-linux

I am running a java 11 application with a dependency on apache-poi. When running the application in docker using the alpine image I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:86)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:497)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.canDisplayUpTo(Font.java:2250)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.singleFont(TextLayout.java:469)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.<init>(TextLayout.java:530)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(SheetUtil.java:285)
        at ImportExportExcel.main(ImportExportExcel.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:84)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1264)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:379)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:324)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
        ... 13 more
```

It seems to me that the underlying issue is that the alpine docker image does not have any fonts by default. I want to know what the minimal fonts are that I need to install in the docker image in order for the code not to fail.

Comment: Running `wb.getFontAt(0)` on a new workbook returns `Calibri`. That is with apache poi 5.2.2 on java 8. Might be different for other versions, but that you can test yourself

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Calibri is the default font for poi, but it doesn't exist on alpine. i need to know how to make this work

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438269

Comment: Is [_headless mode_](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/headless.html) relevant in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The diagnosis is right, alpine images lack fonts and this becomes apparent when producing documents. I have seen this when off-screen rendering UMLs.

`RUN apk add fontconfig ttf-dejavu`

helped in my case, and [here is the working docker file](https://github.com/maciejskorski/plantuml-docker/blob/a0afa5f5d821f249efde990737432562b7aa02b2/Dockerfile#L28).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I went through the stacktrace. In the SheetUtil.java getDefaultCharWidth is called. In case of an internal error as reported by OP you can handle that error when the system property "org.apache.poi.ss.ignoreMissingFontSystem" is set to true. It will return a default char width then instead of rethrowing the error.

So you either set this property to true in your environment or you might add a configuration to your spring application as following:

```
@configuration
public class FontConfiguration {

@PostConstruct
public void setProperty() {
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.ss.ignoreMissingFontSystem", "true");
}
}
```